# Seek slider is not moving nor updating the seek

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following this Video Tutorial on http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1402 I have modified the variables and have converted to jQuery. The Seek Slider doesn't seem to work, I' am not getting any error message on the Console.

When I move the Slider, it fires up the event which are mousemove or mouseup but doesn't move the Slider. Even if I Move the slider manually to a position it still doesn't update the seek.

**JavaScript**

```
var audio, jPlay, jMute, seekslider, seeking = false, seekto, jVolume;
function init_audio_player(){
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "/samples/xxxx.mp3";

    // Set object references
    seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");

    seekslider.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){ seek(event); });
    seekslider.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){ seeking = false; });

    function seek(event){
        if(seeking){
            seekslider.value = event.clientX - seekslider.offsetLeft;
            seekto = audio.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
            audio.currentTime = seekto;
        }
    }

}
window.addEventListener("load", init_audio_player);
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="jPlay" class="icon-play"></a>
<a id="jStop" class="icon-stop"></a>
<input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">
<input id="jVolume" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable called `seeking` is always `false`, at least according to the code you've shown here. So your `seek()` function never does anything. Notice that in the tutorial, there is a listener for `mousedown` that sets `seeking = true;`